# PHP simpleXML parsing

Tags: php, simplexml, nodes

I need currency conversion, euro to dollar.
The European Central bank provides the rates here:
http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml
I can get the USD rate by using the first node, but what if they change the order?
Do I need something more reliable? I have no idea how..

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_file('http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml');
echo "dollar: " . $xml->Cube->Cube->Cube[0]->attributes()->rate;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use XPath to get any node with the attribute @currency equal to "USD", that will do the trick.

```
$xref  = simplexml_load_file('http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml');
$nodes = $xref->xpath('//*[@currency="USD"]');

echo $nodes[0]['rate'];
```

Answer (score 2):

They provide example code at this page:

- http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html

Just click the tab **For Developers**

There is also an (unmaintained) [PEAR Package for Exchange Rates](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_ExchangeRates)

You should not bother if they change the order. If they do, they do.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through simpleXML objects with a `foreach`

```
foreach( $xml->Cube->Cube as $cube ) {
    if( isset( $cube->attributes()->rate ) ) {
         $rate = $cube->attributes()->rate; 
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath

```
$rate = $xml->xpath("//Cube[currency='USD']/rate")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Currently you are assuming the `0th` entry to be `USD` and if the order changes in the future your assumption fails. So to make your application independent of the order, you can check for the `currency` attribute in a loop. The moment you find one with value `"USD"` you can get its corresponding `rate` attribute.